# Parse all strings between strings of a file in Swift

Tags: javascript, regex, macos, swift, nsscanner

I want to build a localization application for my javascript (pebble.js) application. It should find all Strings between `l._("` and `")` or `')` or `",` or `',`.

So for example I have the the line

`console.log(l._("This is a Test") + l._('%@ times %@ equals %@', 2, 4, (2*4)));`

With the Swift application I should get an Array like this:

```
["This is a Test", "%@ times %@ equals %@"]
```

Right now I have no clue how I should manage it. Should I use a Regex, NSScanner or should I split the strings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with NSScanner, but with regexp the solution would be quite easy, with the assumption, that a string has the same delimiter at both ends. (I.e., you don't have stuff like `l._("Hello world')`.) I think that wouldn't be valid syntax in JavaScript, so let's assume that is the case.
Also, let's assume that the strings don't contain any escaped quotes (of the same kind that is used as delimiter), i.e. there are no such strings: `l._("Hello \" world)`.

Now you could use the following two regexps to find strings delimited by double quotes and those delimited by single quotes:

`l._\("((?:[^"])*)"`  -- for double quotes
`l._\('((?:[^'])*)'`  -- for single quotes

Then, you have to run these two regexps on your input, and get the result of the first capturing group for each match. (I'm not sure how exactly swift uses regexps, but note that in many implementation, capturing group #0 is usually the whole match, and capturing group #1 is what is located between the first pair of parenthesis -- you need the latter.)

Also, note that you don't have to care what comes after the closing quote: whether it's a parenthesis, or a comma, it's the same for you, as you only have to look up to the quote.

EDIT: Corrected the regexp (repetition should be inside capturing group).

EDIT2: If we allow escaped quotes, than you can use this regexp for the single quoted case:
`l._\('((?:\\'|[^'])*)'`. And a similar one for the double quoted.
You can play around with the regex on this link:
https://regex101.com/r/tY1jB5/1